What is particle in the syntax?

She took off the level.

Here the off is called a particle. But I don't understand what a particle actually is.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_particle

@StuartF That means it is a part of speech?

Look at the modern thing on Wikipedia. The word off has a stand-alone meaning. It therefore cannot be a particle.

"off" can be a particle in phrases like "blast off". And in "take off" when it refers to something like a airplane or rocket. But in your example I think it's a preposition.

@Barmar In the dull and murky nineteenth century conception of grammar in which a word like off insidiously changes its part of speech according to its grammatical relations, the word "off" is definitely not a preposition here just as in "blast off". It is what such folk would call an "adverb". The reason is that the NP is not a complement of "of". Consider: "She took the level off".

@Araucaria-Him I wasn't really sure if preposition was right, but it's definitely an independent word rather than particle. I might have been think of "It fell off the table."

@StuartF That article is a testament to the fact that Wikipedia should not be taken as any kind of authority abbot anything that is not common knowledge. It's just taken a whole load of completely different uses of the word "particle" and conflated them into a list pretending they're the same thing. What a terrible page.

There are different types of words which are labelled 'particles' by some. Here, as 'take off' is a multi-word verb (called 'phrasal verb' by some) meaning, I assume, 'remove' here (more context needed), and thus a single lexeme according to Crystal's definition, 'off' is a component of a larger lexeme rather than a word in its own right (some prefer a different analysis). There are many such, mimicking prepositions etc. // I'm close-voting as this has been addressed before on ELU.

This question is similar to: When can we change the order of the particle and the verb in a phrasal verb?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. // See also ...

Constituency tests that are needed to differentiate between phrasal verbs and verb + prepositional phrase constructions?, and, for other particles, A to-infinitive is formed with 'to' plus the base form of a verb. What part of speedh is this 'to'?.

@EdwinAshworth The last post you cited deals with a completely different issue of what part of speech to before an infinitival is. Only when you've decided to call it a particle does the post touches on the current issue but only tangentially. The first two posts you cited do more directly touch on the issue of particles, but the questions and answers aren't really helping. If anything, those confused/confusing answers/comments might make the OP wonder what the heck a particle is, rather than give it a clear definition.

@JK2 ... But that's the whole point. 'Particle' is ill-defined. You can write an eloquent and persuasive answer ... but there will be grammarians who disagree with your definition. ishtar's answer is more balanced.

@EdwinAshworth As long as you don't try to define 'particles' as a separate POS, I don't see how and why they're "ill-defined." It's like we have "articles" even though they do not form a separate POS but belong in a POS (determiner). Unlike most other determiners, an article cannot form an NP alone. The whole point is that none of three posts you cited shouldn't be used to close this question.

@EdwinAshworth Now, give me one POS, or more broadly even one grammatical term/concept, if you will, that isn't "ill-defined". If anything, I'm the one who's perhaps the most critical of the existing definitions of grammatical terms, concepts, etc. around here, if you know what I mean. So it's quite surprising that you'd close a valid question simply because you personally regard 'particles' as 'ill-defined'.

Your questions are too short. You need to put more effort into composing your questions. You need to tell us what has led you to ask the question in terms of confusion over some theory or model, what you think the answer is and why, or why you question there even being a clear answer. It is unseemly to expect people to put more effort into answering than you have put into asking the question. What research did you do where, and what did you find? What are your own guesses and why?

Particles do not form a separate part of speech. The term 'particle' was invented not because we don't know what part of speech your off is (Traditional grammar says it's an adverb, for example), but because it exhibits a syntactic behavior that the designated part of speech doesn't normally show.
In your example, if off is an adverb, we cannot explain how it can come between the transitive verb took and its object the level. Normally, an adverb can't come between a transitive verb and its object. One explanation would be that off is so small a unit that it's allowed to come between a transitive verb and its object. Hence the name 'particle', as defined in Merriam-Webster as:

1 a : a minute quantity or fragment
b : a relatively small or the smallest discrete portion or amount of something


"but because it exhibits a syntactic behavior that the designated part of speech doesn't normally show": your personal deduction, I suppose, otherwise you would have provided a source…

@LPH H&P's CGEL, for example, says "The distinctive property of particles  is that they can be positioned between the verb and an NP object with the form of a  proper noun or determiner + common noun. This is what distinguishes down from downstairs in [24]: both can follow the object, but only down can precede it. In general,  object NPs of the above form follow the verb immediately, without intervening adjuncts or complements, and particles constitute the major exception to this ordering." (p. 280).

@LPH But regardless of whether it's just my own observation or is based on a "source," I can say whatever I want to say in my own answer, and you can question it as long as you provide a counterexample or two. Note that even a "source" could be utterly wrong.

Don't take me wrong, I am not questioning your claim, but the basis for your reasoning and your reasoning itself, to which you now give additional support by invoking a distinctive characteristic, become now more convincing in the process of deciding whether to accept a justification you propose as the final say on this question; It's a question I asked myself often without ever being able to come up with  anything satisfying ("adverb or preposition combining with verbs to form phrasal verbs" always appeared wanting to me).  I believe I've learned something now: it would be as simple as that.

I've seen an article, a very persuasive article, saying that articles in MWVs are sufficiently distinct in their behaviour to warrant a separate POS classification. Calling them say 'peripheral adverbs' is a choice, not axiomatic.

@EdwinAshworth Please point me to the article. And you mean "particles in MWVs", not "articles in MWVs".

@EdwinAshworth Oh, and regardless of how persuasive an article you're talking about, that doesn't justify closing this question.

This University of Sussex Grammar Dept article looks at a proposed POS reworking.  //pbrocks gives a definition of a 'particle' in the first question I mention above. That question really demands one. ) And in the second cited question, Fraser's use of the term 'particle' is referenced. Duplicate.

@EdwinAshworth pbrokes says a particle used to be a preposition but now is part of a verb. Just because something is a complement of a verb doesn't mean it is part of a verb. Rather, we call that something part of a verb phrase. So how could you possibly trust someone who doesn't even know the difference between a verb and a verb phrase? // GregLee simply cited a source in an answer that allegedly contains a definition of a particle. AFAIK, this doesn't count as having been discussed in this site. Otherwise, we could simply cite a source in every answer. So, no, it's not a duplicate.

In H&P, and others that preceded them, particle is a syntactic function (aka grammatical relation like subject, object, adjunct etc), not a part of speech. Of course, most particles are prepositions in real life, and that is exactly and precisely how they behave!

The point is that this has been addressed before. If you wish to post a better answer, the earlier thread is the place to do it.

@Araucaria-Him Particle can be a syntactic function if it's defined to include only verb complements such as off. Not if it's defined to include things like to and not as ishtar suggests in another answer.

@EdwinAshworth To disprove your claim that the OP was addressed in an earlier post, I've laid out specific reasons, to which you didn't respond. Moreover, the OP has been reopened anyway, rendering your point moot.

@JK2 Ishtar's post just includes everything that's ever been referred to as a particle, a bit like the awful Wiki post that's been linked to here. There's no principled grammarians going around calling all three of those particles!

@Araucaria-Him Here's an excerpt from "Introduction: Particles through a modern syntactic lens" (2nd page): "[...] it would appear that particles may serve a wide range of syntactic functions. Thus descriptive grammars may i.a. refer to tense, aspect and mood (TAM) particles, locative, directional and other relational particles, valency-related particles, negation particles, interrogative particles, evidential particles and, more generally, discourse-related particles of various kinds, including topic, focus and specificity particles." (cont'd)

"Viewed from a generative perspective, it would therefore
seem that particles can be associated with different clausal and non-clausal domains. More specifically, thinking in terms of the kind of “clausal tripartition” that emerges if we take Chomsky’s (2000) Core Functional Categories (C, T, v) as a point of departure, it seems possible to identify v- (valency- and aspect-related particles), T- (tense and mood) and C (interrogative, evidential and other discourse-related) particles."

@JK2 Yes, that paper addresses a specific cross-linguistic conception of particles which does not apply in the end, to prepositions found in English verb-preposition idioms (or, in fact, to English at all). So, essentially, that type of 'particle' has nothing to do with the English language-specific 'particle' of phrasal verbs. It's just a case of homonyms. Certainly, the adverb not, infinitival-to, and the prepositions found in so-called 'phrasal verbs' do not count as particles ( or, rather, the type of particle discussed in their paper) on their account.

@Araucaria-Him I'm afraid I have to disagree with you that a cross-linguistic approach doesn't apply to English. Last time I checked, English is a language.

@JK2 You misunderstand. It doesn't apply to prepositions in 'phrasal verbs' because they aren't the type of word being discussed. And in the same way that it doesn't apply to English prepositions, that whole conception of particles  doesn't apply to English at all simply because English does not have particles. Just in the same way that a book on tense or grammatical gender wouldn't apply to Mandarin - last time I checked.

@Araucaria-Him I don't think the paper says whatever it says about particles does not apply to English. So why are you trying to put words into their mouth?

@JK2 If you read and understand the paper it is self-evident. If particles are syncategorematic and cannot be part of an extended projection (and thus cannot be complementisers), which English items do you propose the authors would consider to be particles?

@Araucaria-Him They don't particularly talk a lot about English, which, however, doesn't necessarily mean that their discussion of particles is not applicable to English at all. They're specifically using examples from several different languages to study the syntactic nature of particles not just in those languages but in other languages (e.g., English).

@JK2 I ask you again, given what they stipulate about particles, what do you propose are some candidate particles in English?

The term 'particle', rather like the term 'gerund' is derived from an ancient language, Latin, though particles were a much more prominent feature of Greek.  There is a fascinating book on that subject by JD Denniston, published in 1934, called, simply, Greek Particles.  It does not follow that today's use of the term has to be the same as the ancient use, and good reason why it cannot and should not be so. However, some features of the ancient 'part of speech' are still of interest and appear in some English usage.
The ancient languages of Greek and Latin were highly inflected: more so than any of their contemporary descendants.  And, in written form, they were unpunctuated and set out without separation between words. As a result of the former, there needed to be some way of telling a reader that a particular sentence was a question, because the verb itself remained the same.  So in Greek, the particle ara preceded the verb, while in Latin the word 'ne' followed it. These 'particles' could be said to 'mean' something like 'look out: question coming'.  But it is fair to say that the words have no more meaning that does the question mark, which appears at the end of a sentence in English presumably in case the reader has forgotten. The particle had no influence on the mood (now called  'mode') of the verb or the case or gender of nouns.  Schoolboys and schoolgirls studying Greek when I was at school would have used the Primer of Greek Grammar, first published in 1880 and still in print. They provided their own definition of particles, which is, I think clearer than any of the definitions I have found in contemporary dictionaries (Page 199 sqq of the 1990 edition).

In addition to the Conjunctions used in introducing the dependent moods..., there are in Greek a number of words used partly to combine sentences, and called Conjunctions, partly to give emphasis to particular expressions, and called Particles.  The same word may indeed be a Conjunction and a Particle. The abundance and variety of these words is one of the most striking characteristics Greek.

This is not the ancient world, however, with words separated and punctuation in use. Most of them were very short - mostly of two to four or five letters.  They are used to shape the sentence, without necessarily affecting the meaning in terms of truth conditions.  In addition to the interrogative particle 'ara' in Greek or 'ne' in Latin, a speaker/writer could signal that the expected answer was 'yes', by using instead the particle arou (Greek) or nonne (Latin), or could signal the opposite by using instead the particle(s) 'ara may (αρα μη).  They are indicating to us 'how to take the sentence'.  Latin does the same, using the words nonne and num respectively.  In English, verbal gymnastics are needed for the same purpose.

You are on holiday, aren't you? or You aren't on holiday are you?, respectively, (or Are you really on holiday?).

The Greek historian and failed general, Thucydides, loved the use of the pair men (μεν) and de (δε) to guide his audience. The first of these is telling the reader that the statement that comes next is going to be followed by something that contrasts with it and we'll know the contrast is with us, when we see/hear that second word. English does not have an equivalent, other than the clumsily adverbial "on the one hand x but on the other hand y".
Other particles signal the attitude or emphasis of the speaker/writer to what is being said. Perhaps the best definition is that of Abbott and Mansfield in their Primer of Greek Grammar originally published in the late 19th century.

In addition to the Conjunctions used in introducing the dependent moods which are treated of under Adverbial sentences, there are in Greek a number of words  used partly to combine sentences, there are in Greek a number of words used partly to combine sentences, and called Conjunctions, partly to give emphasis to particular expressions, and called Particles. The same word may indeed be a Conjunction and a Particle.  The abundance and variety of these is one of the most striking characteristics of Greek.

The contemporary usage is not quite the same as these, though there is an overlap, in words like indeed, which do not influence the literal meaning or truth conditions of a sentence or clause but lend weight or emphasis. The simplest way of looking at it is to think of it as whatever is not one of the standard parts of speech.  What do the dictionaries say?  The best attempt I have found is in the Oxford Companion to the English Language.

Particle [14c through French from Latin particula a small part]. a word that does not change its form through inflection and does not fit easily into the established system of parts of speech. Among individual words so classed are the negative particle not (its contraction n't), the infinitival partical to (to go, to run), the imperative particles do, don't (Do tell me, Don't tell me) and let, let's as in (Let me see now; Let's go). There is also a set of  adverbial and prepositional particles that combine with verbs to form phrasal verbs (out in Look out!, up as in Turn up) and prepositional verbs (at as in get at, for as in "care for). The term pragmatic particle is sometimes used for words that play a role in maintaining discourse and are also known as fillers and discourse markers: oh, ah, well, yes, no, actually, anyway.

This account has the disadvantage that it lacks examples of actual sentences in which particles are used. But much the same can be said for the standard dictionaries I have consulted.
The Cambridge English Dictionary has

A word or part of a word that has a grammatical purpose but often has little or no meaning.

This omits the particles like "oh" and so forth.
Collins gives a more similar account, confined mainly to preposotional phrasal verbs.

In grammar, a particle is a preposition such as 'into' or an adverb such as 'out' which can combine with a verb to form a phrasal verb.


a unit of speech expressing some general aspect of meaning or some connective or limiting relation and including the articles, most prepositions and conjunctions, and some interjections and adverbs.

I would say that the Companion explanation is the most helpful in understanding the idea, and one which has at least a remote link with the origin of the term, as well as its use.
